# Prevent FragmentView loading the RecyclerView until its focused?

Tags: android, tabs

I have a simple `FragmentView` in my app and 3 tabs. All 3 tabs have `RecyclerView`, the problem is first two tabs are not that complex, while third tab uses some complex operations and slows down the app making it lag while it's doing those operations. My question is: How can I prevent `FragmentView` to call `onCreateView` until it's focused?
Right now the third tab starts doing those operations when second tab is focused. I want it to start doing those methods when third tab is focused.
This is my code:

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

and this is my adapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                RingtonesActivityFragment Ringtones = new RingtonesActivityFragment();
                return Ringtones;
            case 1:
                FavoritesActivityFragment Favorites = new FavoritesActivityFragment();
                return Favorites;
            case 2:
                MySongsActivityFragment Songs = new MySongsActivityFragment();
                return Songs;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

and Tabs:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
...
...
...
         return rootView;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewPager` will load 1 page to either side of the current page by default. Even if you set `setOffscreenPageLimit` to less than 1, it'll reset itself to 1. There is no getting around this unless you modify the `ViewPager` class to your liking.

To help with lazily executing code you can use `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and its method `onPageSelected(int position)` to find out which tab is currently in focus. You can then postpone the work required once the `Fragment` is in focus.

I'd also add that if you're doing work which causes lag in your UI, you might want to consider moving the work to a background thread. If the work is layout related and you can't do it on a background thread use Hierarchy Viewer or Systrace to help you optimize.

Comment: Well it's not a problem since that tab has progress bar and text to tell the user that application is doing something, but if tab is activated and not displayed then there is a short lag, 4-5 sec but still can be annoying since the application is very simple. And there is no excuse for lag. I will look into this and if there are no better answers or work-around for this i will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: @SlimC. 4-5 seconds is __a lot__ of lag in terms of UX. This much work should not be happening on the main thread.

Comment: yeah but during that time user can't do anything. Think of it as a loading screen. And I just checked it's doing in background, but yeah although the loading time greatly depends on how many files user have. The greater the number the longer time is required to finish.